# what can I do to make a file open when double clicking on several items that I have as a string in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

'''
I need that in a listbox in tkinter, I can introduce a list of buttons generated by a cycle and that each button when pressed can open a specific file.

2. Is it possible to send some items to a listbox and double click on them to open files?.

The image shown below, has some items but those items are as a string of characters, I need if there is the possibility to generate some kind of code that when I click on those items, it allows me to open a specific file
'''

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO1oD.png)

from tkinter import *
import webbrowser as wb
import tkinter as tk
import os, sys
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter.ttk import Label, Style
from tkinter.font import  Font, BOLD

```
pantalla=tk.Tk()
pantalla.title("parque explora")
pantalla.geometry("700x500")
pantalla.config(bg="red")
pantalla.config(cursor="hand2")
```

```
def abrirarchivo(nombre_dic1):
    num_abrir_arch=0
    list_problemstec=os.listdir(nombre_dic1)
    wb.open_new(nombre_dic1+list_problemstec[num_abrir_arch-1])# esta funcion todavía no se ejecuta en el código, es una posible idea que voy a utilizar pero ignorenla por favor
```

```
def presentecion(nombre_dic):
        c=1
        list_problemstec=os.listdir(nombre_dic)
        for a in list_problemstec:
            variable4=(str(c)+" "+"."+a[:-4])
            listbox.insert(tk.END,(variable4))
           # boton_enviar=tk.Button(pantalla, text=variable)      
            c+=1
```

```
def entregar_datos(problema):
    
    problems=[]#esta lista contiene todos los posibles probelmas
    problemstec=["teclado","teclas","tecla","teclados"]#problemas de teclado unicamente
    #se recorre la lista indicada y se agregan esos problemas a la lista general (problems)
    for i in problemstec:
        problems.append(i)   
        
        
    problemswifi=["wifi","red","internet","conexion","redes"]#problemas de wifi unicamente
    #se recorre la lista indicada y se agregan esos problemas a la lista general (problems)
    for i in problemswifi:
        problems.append(i)


    problemsmonitor=["pantalla","monitor","pantallas","monitores"]#problemas de monitor unicamente
    #se recorre la lista indicada y se agregan esos problemas a la lista general (problems)
    for i in problemsmonitor:
        problems.append(i)
        
         
    problemsmouse=["mouse","raton","mause"]#problemas de mouse unicamente
    #se recorre la lista indicada y se agregan esos problemas a la lista general (problems)
    for i in problemsmouse:
        problems.append(i)
        
        
    problemsdrive=["drive","google_drive","nube"]#problemas de drive   
    for i in problemsdrive:
        problems.append(i)
                        
    problemsmeet=["meet","met","mit","main"]
    for i in problemsmeet:
        problems.append(i)
        
        
    problemscarpeta=["compartir carpeta", "recuperar carpeta", "bloqueo de carpeta", "carpetas", "carpeta"]
    for i in problemscarpeta:
        problems.append(i)
        
        
    problemsdatafono=[]
    for i in problemsdatafono:
        problems.append(i)
        
        
    problemsoffice=[]
    for i in problemsoffice:
        problems.append(i)
        
        
    problemsimpresora=[]
    for i in problemsimpresora:
        problems.append(i)
        
        
    infosistem=[]
    for i in infosistem:
        problems.append(i)
        
        
    problemsred=[]
    for i in problemsred:
        problems.append(i)
        
        
    problemssap=[]
    for i in problemssap:
        problems.append(i)
        
        
    problemsscore=[]
    for i in problemsscore:
        problems.append(i)
    
                
    problema.lower()#se pone lo que ingreso el usuario en minuscula
    #problema=problemas.split()#se divide en espacios
    defoult=0
    problem_find = ""
    
    #for i in problema:#se mira que lo que ingrese el usuario coincida con algun problema
    for j in problems:
            if problema == j:
                if problema in problemstec:
                    #print("Usted tiene problemas con: "+i)
                    defoult+=1
                    problem_find = problema
                    break
                elif problema in problemswifi:
                    #print("Usted tiene problemas con: "+i)
                    defoult+=1
                    problem_find = problema
                    break
                elif problema in problemsmonitor:
                    #print("Usted tiene problemas con: "+i)
                    defoult+=1
                    problem_find = problema
                    break
                elif problema in problemsmouse:
                    #print("Usted tiene problemas con: "+i)
                    defoult+=1
                    problem_find = problema
                    break
                elif problema in problemsdrive:
                   #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)
                    defoult+=1
                    problem_find = problema
                    break
                elif problema in problemsmeet:
                    #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)
                    defoult+=1
                    problem_find=problema
                    break
                elif problema in problemscarpeta:
                    #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)
                    defoult+=1
                    problem_find=problema
                    break
                elif problema in problemsdatafono:
                    #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)
                    defoult+=1
                    problem_find=problema
                    break
                elif problema in problemsimpresora:
                    #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)
                    defoult+=1
                    problem_find=problema
                    break
                elif problema in infosistem:
                    #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)
                    defoult+=1
                    problem_find=problema
                    break
                elif problema in problemsred:
                    #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)
                    defoult+=1
                    problem_find=problema
                    break
                elif problema in problemssap:
                    #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)
                    defoult+=1
                    problem_find=problema
                    break
                elif problema in problemsscore:
                    #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)
                    defoult+=1
                    problem_find=problema
                    break
                elif problema in problemsoffice:
                    #print("usted tiene problemas con: "+i)
                    defoult+=1
                    problem_find=problema
                    break
```

```
    if defoult == 0:
              listbox.insert(tk.END,("NO ENTIENDO SU PETICIÓN. POR FAVOR INGRESE UNA PALABRA CLAVE"))          
    else:
                
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            if problem_find in problemstec:
                name='C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/teclado/'
                presentecion(name)
  
        #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            elif problem_find in problemsmouse:
                name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/mouse/"
                presentecion(name)
               
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            elif problem_find in problemsmonitor:
                #carpeta_interna='C:/Users/HP/Documents/problemas/monitor'
                name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/monitor/"
                presentecion(name)
              
        #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            elif problem_find in problemsdrive:
                
                name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/drive/"
                presentecion(name)  
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
            elif problem_find in problemsmeet:
                
                name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/meet/"
                presentecion(name)
                
            elif problem_find in problemscarpeta:
                #
                name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/carpetas/"
                presentecion(name)
                
            elif problem_find in problemsdatafono:
                #
                name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/datafono/"
                presentecion(name)
                
            elif problem_find in problemsoffice:
                #
                name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/office/"
                presentecion(name)
                
            elif problem_find in problemsimpresora:
                #
                name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/impresora/"
                presentecion(name)
                
            elif problem_find in infosistem:
                #
                name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/informacion de mi equipo/"
                presentecion(name)
            
            elif problem_find in problemsred:
                #
                name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/red/"
                presentecion(name)
                
            elif problem_find in problemssap:
                #
                name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/sap/"
                presentecion(name)
                
            elif problem_find in problemsscore:
                #
                name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/score/"
                presentecion(name)
                
            elif problem_find in problemswifi:
                #
                name="C:/Users/MANUEL/Documents/problemas/wifi/"
                presentecion(name)
```

```
problema=StringVar()
num_abrir_arch=StringVar()


listbox=tk.Listbox(pantalla)#caja grande donde ira la lista de diapositivas
listbox.place(relx=0.01,rely=0.05,relwidth=0.9,relheight=0.8)#ubicacion de la caja, largo, altura, ancho

barra_pantalla=Scrollbar(pantalla, command=listbox.yview())
barra_pantalla.place(relx=0.92, rely=0.2,relheight=0.2 )
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=barra_pantalla)


cuadro_problema=Entry(pantalla, textvariable=problema)
cuadro_problema.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.9)


boton_enviar=tk.Button(pantalla, text="enviar dato", command=lambda:entregar_datos(problema.get()))
boton_enviar.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.939)

boton_abrir_archivo=tk.Button(pantalla, text="abrir archivo")#boton para enviar datos
boton_abrir_archivo.place(relx=0.35,rely=0.9)#tamaña del boton


pantalla.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, create a dictionary with the items in your listbox and key and values as the links you want to open. Then use `bind` to bind to `<Double-Button-1>` and then index the item you just clicked from the dictionary and then open the link.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello, can someone please help me. 

I have two functions, one shows me some items in string and the other one opens some links and I need that each string is with its link and when I click on a string it opens the link. help please

Comment: Delrius, thank you very much for the information, I have tried to do what you indicate but I don't understand how to do what you indicate in a dictionary, can you give me an example?